# Ansible Inventory scripts

Tags: inventory, ansible, digital-ocean

I am using the digital_ocean inventory script that is shipped with ansible which is working fine.  However, I am trying to access the host information from that script inside a playbook.  Do these values get saved as variables that can be accessed from inside the playbook?  If so, does anyone know what the name of the variables are?

I am not sure if this data is stored in the global variables namespace (or whatever it is called) for use in playbooks later.  Do I need to make a separate call to the inventory script  later?  I would like to not have to do this since each call to the script takes a while.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The variable are available directly in the global scope.

Check the intro [inventory documentation](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/intro_inventory.html).